# Building a unified object from CDC events via kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, cdc

I am trying to build my understanding with using CDC , Kafka streams.

I want to build a system called 'Order Store' that represents a unified data model of all orders booked in multiple order booking systems. Assume I have order booking systems that create orders in their own format in their own tables. These systems have CDC setup and push row changes as events to their Kafka topics. One Kafka topic per table in the order booking system. From here how do I get to creating a complete unified order in the order store.

1. Where will I be able to get details for all of the order information from the source order booking system because from CDC I only get specific row changes in my Kafka topic.
2. When I am using streams to join Kafka topics - let's say I have Kafka topics 'Order Event' topic and 'Order Details' topic. Order details was changed and it created an event in Order Details Kafka topic. If I try to join it with order in order topic I might not find the order info as Kafka stores only last x days worth of data. In this case what is done to build a order object that needs order and order details?

Comment: 1) _from CDC I only get specific row changes in my Kafka topic_  - So? You can build a KTable, or do an ID lookup against the original table to "hydrate" your event information. ... 2) _Kafka stores only last x days worth of data_ - No. That is configurable, and completely ignores the concept of compacted topics, which KTables rely on

Comment: Thanks for explaining point 1. With respect to point 2 - I agree how much you can store is configurable. My query is when you join streams and you don't find a join because say order is missing, what do you do to bring in order info from source so that join will happen between order and order details or is there a better approach to take to build a complete order that represents the current state?

Comment: Yes, you use a KTable (which will store all existing orders) to ensure that all data will exist and can be joined.

Comment: I read about KTable and it says it is a representation of a change log stream when there is an update. Pardon my ignorance here, the Order never changed and only OrderItem changed, so KTable will not have any info about Order isn't it? Let's say Order was created 2 years back and Order Item got modified today. Appreciate if you can give me more context here.

Comment: Think of it as a materialized view. If you have a topic (or a database you can read with Debezium into a topic) with data from "2 years ago". Then you can still build a Ktable from it without needing to update it. Regardless, you still have to execute a remote lookup query against something